# How to deploy unmanaged package using the ANT Migration Tool

Tags: ant, migration-tool

We are trying to deploy an unmanaged package we are developing within a Developer org to a separate sandbox using the ANT Migration Tool. Im using the following to retrieve the package...

```
<target name="retrievePkg">
  <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" packageNames="mypackagename"/>
</target> 

...and to deploy...

<target name="deployCode">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged" rollbackOnError="true" testLevel="NoTestRun" singlePackage="true">
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

This deploys the code/components to the destination org but not under the 'mypackagename' package we've retrieved from the source org.

How do we deploy code/components as a package to the destination org?

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the migration tool for this? Can't you just generate a link for the package in your developer edition org? See: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging under "Packaging Concepts > Unmanaged packages"